# Docusign Click: is there a way to authenticate the user before starting Docusign Click process?

Tags: docusignapi

is there a way to authenticate the user before starting Docusign Click process ?
I would like to authenticate the user by SMS, but I can't find anything in Docusign Api reference about it.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't, unless you build it yourself.
The DocuSign Click product is meant for quick acceptance of terms and such. If you want more elaborate flows (including two factor auth etc.) you can use the regular eSignature product.